# In inheritance what is upcast and downcast in hierarchy?

Tags: java

I have class Foo which have eat() method and a Class Moo which extends Foo and overrided the eat() method and have additional method ate(). Now how do I define what is upcast and down cast in this inheritance tree. Can anyone explain??
`Foo f = new Moo(); // line x`
`Moo m = Moo(new Foo()); // line y`

My question is that what is downcast here or how do we define downcast in terms of instantiation. Iine x or y and which methods I can use while down casting .

Comment: You will not be able to create an instance of Moo and assign it to a variable of type Foo.

Comment: Robert that's valid I can create an instance of Moo and assign it to reference type Foo but finally I'll be able to access the eat () method of Moo class but ate() method will not be available to use

Comment: Right @ashishraaj.. with Parent's reference you can call only those methods which are present in Parent class because it is checked at compile time that the reference must have the method that is being called on that reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upcasting - `Foo f = new Moo(); // Parent reference in being used to hold child class object reference and it is allowed in Java`

Downcasting - `Moo m = new Foo(); // Child reference is beeing used to parent object's reference and it i not allowed in Java. It will give you a compile time error.`

However, if you write the following code, it will compile fine but break at runtime ultimately.

```
Moo m = (Moo) new Foo();
```